# How to fix 'error trying to exec 'cc1obj': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, gcc, error-handling

I am running Ubuntu in a virtual machine and I keep getting this error when I try to execute `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o test.dll hello.m -objc` in order to cross-compile an objective c project for windows.
I get the following error:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1obj': execvp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is it, and how / from where did you install the cross-compiler toolchain? it looks like maybe a required Objective-C++ compiler component is missing?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and I first installed gcc and after that I installed the cross-compiler toolchain mingw-w64. I also installed gobjc and gobjc++ package.

Comment: Did you install `gobjc++-mingw-w64`? if not, try doing so

Comment: It solved the error! Thanks :) Unfortunately there is now another error "fatal error: Foundation/Foundation.h: No such file or directory
", which refers to the standard foundation-header I import in my m file.

Comment: I'd guess you'd need a full GNUStep toolchain to get that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the corresponding Objective-C++ cross compiler package, either from your favorite GUI package manager or via the command line using

```
sudo apt install gobjc++-mingw-w64
```

This should install both `gobjc++-mingw-w64-i686` and `gobjc++-mingw-w64-x86-64` allowing you to build Objective-C++ code targeting both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows platforms.