# 'cc1obj': execvp: No such file

Tags: compiling, gcc, g++

I'm trying to install cider by using the command

```
pip3 install cider
```

but got

```
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1obj': execvp: No such file or directory
```

what should I check ? or install ?

i tried to install `sudo apt-get install libgnustep-gui-dev` and the error become

```
  cider/_osx.m:1:9: fatal error: AppKit/AppKit.h: No such file or directory
     #import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: You have not even said what version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'error trying to exec 'cc1obj': execvp: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/937293/how-to-fix-error-trying-to-exec-cc1obj-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @David Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: @Rinzwind i tried the link before but the error is still

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 → 'cc1obj' : Probably install `gobjc-7` . ..... "AppKit/AppKit.h" : Install `libgnustep-gui-dev`